# Yahoo's Weather Class stopped cause of disabling file_get_contents by host server

Tags: php

I use Yahoo's Weather Class It works well
 these days ,The host Provider disabled some functions are:
 fopen - fwrite-fread-file_get_contents
 These functions are used to read xml file from Yahoo and (write –read) Cache in TMP file
inside the server,
 Functions found in the files of Classic.

So please those who have  ability to change the functions of existing files
there help will be appreciate
 I read that we can use the curl function but I cannot edit the class

[Download  the class](http://www.voegeli.li/development/class.yahoo.weather/class.yahoo.weather.rar),,,,,,,

Comment: Speak to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do would be to use an alternate provider, or alternate software in general, perhaps enlisting a developer to create a solution that better fits your needs